# Buscar MAC em PHP

Tags: php, mac

Preciso filtrar o tipo de acesso que irá ser feito dentro do sistema, poderá acessar apenas de um computador em específico, com IP randômico.

Há alguma forma de buscar em PHP ou jQuery, ou qualquer outra linguagem o endereço do MAC? Assim cadastramos no banco de dados o MAC e verifico se permite acesso ou não.